# Excel Dependent List Push back

Tags: excel

I have created a dependent list drop down for a range of cells. However when I change the cell it is dependent one while the drop down changes the options i can choose it doesn't push back an error that the data validation is still incorrect.

As an example

I chose High and that lets me select 80%, 90% or 100%. So i chose 90%

But when I change it to Medium (which should only be 40%-70%) it still shows that the 90% is valid.

Thanks,

Comment: So when you select Medium, are you looking for Excel to bring you back to that drop-down and force you to change it from 90% to something else?

Comment: Exactly. I just want to make sure that it forces me to make the change so that I don't accidentally add a invalid value.

Comment: I think you'd need a `Worksheet_Change` event to force you to make that change then. Are you using VBA now or some kind of `INDIRECT` formula?

Comment: Indirect Formula.

Comment: Yeah I don't think there's any kind of built in functionality to force you to change the value of that cell, as the `INDIRECT` formula drop-down list is already kind of a workaround. You would need a `Worksheet_Change()` event to constantly be checking the values. I can post a small example for you.

Comment: PROTIP: There are inherent limitations to Objects placed on sheets. You will find many things that you would expect to be able to do cannot be done. When making an interface in Excel you always want to use WinForms to get the full power of Visual Basic, and all the functionality you would expect. 
https://www.contextures.com/xlUserForm01.html

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example where if the value in `B1` is set to something greater than 70 and the value in `A1` is switched to "Medium", then the focus is brought to `B1` and the dropdown list is opened:

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then
    If Range("A1").Value = "Medium" And Range("B1").Value > 70 Then
        Range("B1").Activate
        SendKeys "%{down}", True
        DoEvents
        SendKeys "{SCROLLLOCK}"
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

Forces open the list like this:

[image: img1]